# What's the best way to determine if an Android device is able to provide good ActivityRecognition results

Tags: android, android-sensors

I have been using Google's [ActivityRecognitionApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) to try to determine when an Android device is being moved. On most devices I've tried this gives pretty decent results. But on some devices I mainly get an activity of "still" with a few "tilting" and "unknown".

I assume that this poor performance of the ActivityRecognitionApi is due to the sensors available on a device, given that the ActivityRecognitionApi uses these, from the documentation:

> The activities are detected by periodically waking up the device and reading short bursts of sensor data. It only makes use of low power sensors in order to keep the power usage to a minimum.

What I want to be able to do is determine, for any given device, if I can rely on the ActivityRecognitionApi or not.

Again in the documentation it says

> To conserve battery, activity reporting may stop when the device is 'STILL' for an extended period of time. It will resume once the device moves again. This only happens on devices that support the Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION hardware.

Which clearly states that a device that supports Sensor.TYPE_SIGNIFICANT_MOTION is relevant, but it's not clear, at least to me, from this, that this sensor is actually required to provide good Activity Recognition results.

So what is the best way of determining if a device is going to give good Activity Recognition results?

As an amusing (at least to me) aside, I'm particularly fond of results such as:

```
activity: unknown
activity_confidence: 50%
```